# Testing a Spring 2.5 Form Controller

Tags: spring, unit-testing

I am adding automated tests to an existing Spring 2.5 codebase that is working in production. I am trying to test the onSubmit() method in my controller.

This is the XML configuration for the controller's views:

```
<property name="formView" value="createPublicBroadcastsForm" />
<property name="successView" value="redirect:createBroadcastsResults.htm" />
```

Here is my JUnit test:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
}

@Test
public void displayForm() throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mv = controller.handleRequest(request, response);
    assertViewName(mv, controller.getFormView());
    }

@Test
public void testSubmitCreate() throws Exception {

    request.setMethod("POST");
    request.addParameter("title", "qwerty");
    request.addParameter("startDate", "02/22/2013 09:00 AM");
    request.addParameter("hours", "1");
    request.addParameter("minutes", "1");
    request.addParameter("seconds", "1");
    request.addParameter("repeats", "None");

    ModelAndView mv;
    try {
        mv = controller.handleRequest(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    assertViewName(mv, controller.getSuccessView());
}
```

The assertion in displayForm() passes, but the one in testSubmitCreate() fails because the view name in the ModelAndView is "createPublicBroadcastsForm", not the expected "redirect:createBroadcastsResults.htm"

A few things I've looked at is that controller.handleRequest() does not throw an exception, the onSubmit() method of the controller is not even called, and I did an override of isFormSubmission() to print the value after calling super.isFormSubmission(), and it returns true.

Also, if I change the test to call the controller's onSubmit() directly instead of handleRequest(), the test passes:

```
PublicBroadcastCommand command = new PublicBroadcastCommand();
command.setTitle("qwerty");
command.setStartDate(DateUtils.createDate(2013, 2, 22, 9));
command.setHours(1);
command.setMinutes(1);
command.setSeconds(1);
command.setRepeats("None");
ModelAndView mv = controller.onSubmit(request, response, command, null);
assertViewName(mv, controller.getSuccessView());
```

So I'm wondering if I should test the controller by invoking handleRequest() or onSubmit() (or both, where onSubmit() is a unit test, and handleRequest() is more of an integration test)?  And any thoughts on where I'm going wrong with trying to test by invoking handleRequest()?